# Is the electricity produced by lightning storm AC or DC?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons

we know that the thunder can produce electricity. I was wandering whether this electricity will be AC or DC.

Comment: It's DC rather than AC in the sense that the current is predominantly flowing in one direction, but as you can probably guess by watching a lightning strike it's not a steady, constant DC current. Also, clouds can be either positively or negatively charged with respect to the ground, so the current flow is not always in the same direction for all lightning strikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current in a bolt of lightning varies with time, but is not periodic, so it can be represented as either a DC or an AC current. This is because any time-varying DC current can be represented as a superposition* of AC currents (here meaning sine or cosine functions), the amplitudes of which are constant in time. The amplitudes of the AC components can be found by taking the Fourier transform.

*The superposition does not necessarily have to be countable, and in the aperiodic case is usually uncountable.